# DataGrid WPF add button to column

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using DataGridin my WPF, I have faced some problems. If I undersand correctly, if I use CanUserAddRow="false" I should have an empty row when I run my app and as I have one column with button, I should be able to add some "onClick" action to it. Not only I can't see the row, but also, when it comes to code, Visual Studio informs me that I have nothing like "my_button". Why is that?

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="false">
<DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Button x:Name="my_button" Click="onClick">First button</Button>
      </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the claim to have an empty row, as the data grid will display what you have bound (or manually populated).  I don't see anything being bound, so it's just going to be empty.  Your button "my_button" isn't going to be in the code-behind because it's in a Template.  There will be multiple (or zero) instances of your button.  Lastly... what is your actual question (i.e., what are you trying to accomplish)?

Comment: I don't want to populate it at all. I am about to create a collection of rows that will be growing any time user decided to add some information. I know that I could use ListView with GridView, however DataGrid is what I like more. So it is enough to declare one row to work with anything? Oh, and maybe You know how to change name of specific button from DataGrid after its being clicked?

Comment: Where will the row collection live?  Database?  Session?  Why is the button to add a row even in the grid?  What button(s) did you want in the row after created?

Comment: New rows will be added on button click. When there will be a row, it must be a button as I need few "on click actions" to perform for one cell. I am not sure if I understand correctly what it means "row collection live", but if I am then that is a collection created in the form (?) while the program is on the run

Comment: Essentially, row collection would be the ItemsSource.  And you mention you like DataGrid more, but you seem to fundamentally misunderstand how to use it.  You've got a DataGrid, with one statically-defined column, but no Items, so nothing will display.  If you _did_ add rows, each row is just going to be a single cell consisting of your button.  Can you mock-up a screen of what you had in mind for your form to look?